# How to check XMLNode is exist or not in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xmlnode

I am writing Windows Phone 8 application, and I am getting XML data from web service,in some response, in my XML document I am getting some "Tags" and in other response I do not getting those tags, so how do I check that XNode is exist or not?
See my XML document below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Group>
     <Id>205647</Id>
     <Name>Docs</Name>
   </Group>

   <Group>
    <Id>205648</Id>
    <Name>Photos</Name>
   </Group>
</root>
```

Now, in above document, the Descendant "GROUP" is exist in some results and doesn't exist in other results,How do I check that?

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension method like this :

```
public static string TryGetElementValue(this XElement parentEl, string elementName, string defaultValue = null) 
{
    var foundEl = parentEl.Element(elementName);
    if(foundEl != null)
    {
         return foundEl.Value;
    }
    else
    {
         return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

This approach allows you to keep a clean code with isolating the check of element presence. It also allow you to define a default value, which can be helpful

Comment: user3683136, thanx man, how do I call it, in calling there are some problems!!thank you very much!!

Comment: like this: id = Group.TryGetElementValue("Id")

Answer (score 1):

You could go through all nodes with the `XmlTextReader` and look for a specific `XmlNode` Name.

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Try this snippet with your xml:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load("your.xml");

  //Select the book node with the matching attribute value.
  XmlNode nodeToFind;
  XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

  // Selects all the title elements that have an attribute named group
  nodeToFind = root.SelectSingleNode("//title[@group]");

  if( nodeToFind != null )
  {
       // It was found, manipulate it.
  }
  else
 {
       // It was not found.
  }
```

Have a look at this too. [updating an existing xml file in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056346/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: anonshankar, I am not getting XmlElement and XmlNode in my code behind file, how to over-come this??Thank you!!

Comment: @NiteshKothari did you add the namespace? 
using System.Xml

Comment: anonshankar, yes man,I have added it!!XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
I am getting XElement and XNode.Thank you!!

Comment: anonshankar, No,I have not executed, because I am not getting those XmlNode and XElement.Once code will done,then I check!!Thank you!!

Comment: yep that would be better. But as far as I know if you've got the namespace you should be able to access the XML properties. Aren't you getting any kind of squiggly under the code?

Comment: what does it say when you hover over?

Comment: The type or naamespace 'XmlNode' couldn't be found!!

Comment: That means you're missing this namespace. Recheck whether you're having it
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.aspx
Using System.Xml